# compare values in list

Tags: python, list, compare

I have list as shown below:

```
abc = 
[
 [ 
   [True, 08JUN2015 00:00, 13JUN2015 00:00, False], 
   [True, 06JUL2015 00:00, 11JUL2015 00:00, True, A, B, C], 
   [True, 28SEP2015 00:00, 03OCT2015 00:00, True, P, Q, R]
 ], 
 [ 
   [True, 18MAY2015 00:00, 23MAY2015 00:00, True, A, B, C], 
   [True, 29DEC2014 00:00, 03JAN2015 00:00, False], 
   [True, 21SEP2015 00:00, 26SEP2015 00:00, True, X, Y, Z]  
 ], 
 [
   [True, 13APR2015 00:00, 18APR2015 00:00, True, D, E, F], 
   [True, 21DEC2015 00:00, 26DEC2015 00:00, True, P, Q, R], 
   [False, 06APR2015 00:00, 11APR2015 00:00, True, Z, U, Y]
 ], 
 [
   [True, 13JUL2015 00:00, 18JUL2015 00:00, True, A,B,C], 
   [True, 09NOV2015 00:00, 14NOV2015 00:00, False], 
   [True, 05JAN2015 00:00, 10JAN2015 00:00, True, A, X, Z], 
   [False, 19OCT2015 00:00, 24OCT2015 00:00, True, B, Z, A], 
   [True, 20JUL2015 00:00, 25JUL2015 00:00, True, E, F, R]  
 ], 
 [
   [True, 23FEB2015 00:00, 28FEB2015 00:00, True, E, R, N],  
   [True, 07DEC2015 00:00, 12DEC2015 00:00, False, W, T, P], 
   [True, 20JUL2015 00:00, 25JUL2015 00:00, True, R, U, Y]
 ]
 [
   [True, 23FEB2015 00:00, 28FEB2015 00:00, True, A, V, D],  
   [True, 07DEC2015 00:00, 12DEC2015 00:00, True, E, Q, R], 
   [True, 20JUL2015 00:00, 25JUL2015 00:00, True, W, R, X]
 ]
]
```

what would be the best way to compare the list of list and check in list that first available record where the first element of list (Bool) is equal to the fourth element of the list (Bool value) for all the 'True' values present in the internal list.

so, for the above list it should check in list
result should be first available 'list' in the list abc, where all 1st position and 4th positions are True irrespective of False in 1st position.

```
 result = [ 
       [True, 18MAY2015 00:00, 23MAY2015 00:00, True, A, B, C], 
       [True, 29DEC2014 00:00, 03JAN2015 00:00, False], 
       [True, 21SEP2015 00:00, 26SEP2015 00:00, True, X, Y, Z]  
     ]
```

check and compare only the 'True' field in list and return the list with all values with True.

Comment: What is the output you are expecting from the above example. Will help to make it clearer. Have you tried anything ?

Answer (score 3):

**This code works:**

```
from itertools import chain

the_list = [
 [ 
   [True, "08JUN2015 00:00", "13JUN2015 00:00", False], 
   [True, "06JUL2015 00:00", "11JUL2015 00:00", True, 1309024584, 'V4YK+lysQgeLXVx9TrkzxQ==', "05JUL2015 00:00"], 
   [True, "28SEP2015 00:00", "03OCT2015 00:00", True, 1309024632, 'lYDIi9ieSoy8nVdVeiBk8Q==', "27SEP2015 00:00"]
 ], 

 [ 
   [True, "18MAY2015 00:00", "23MAY2015 00:00", True, 1309024556, 'lDp+xHboQ2u8NmNTrDcHug==', "17MAY2015 00:00"], 
   [True, "29DEC2014 00:00", "03JAN2015 00:00", False], 
   [True, "21SEP2015 00:00", "26SEP2015 00:00", True, 1309024628, 'BVNYf4MyT0S+PBjFWBUq1A==', "20SEP2015 00:00"]  
 ], 

 [
   [True, "13APR2015 00:00", "18APR2015 00:00", True, 1309024536, 'pwuzfaUuQrm6n00oBoXHwA==', "12APR2015 00:00"], 
   [True, "21DEC2015 00:00", "26DEC2015 00:00", True, 1309024680, 'RmbuGHxbSvKZnh9z6BIj7A==', "20DEC2015 00:00"], 
   [False, "06APR2015 00:00", "11APR2015 00:00", False]
 ], 
]

print [x for x in chain(*the_list) if x[0] is True and x[3] is True]
```

**Output:**

```
[
    [True, '06JUL2015 00:00', '11JUL2015 00:00', True, 1309024584, 'V4YK+lysQgeLXVx9TrkzxQ==', '05JUL2015 00:00'],
    [True, '28SEP2015 00:00', '03OCT2015 00:00', True, 1309024632, 'lYDIi9ieSoy8nVdVeiBk8Q==', '27SEP2015 00:00'],
    [True, '18MAY2015 00:00', '23MAY2015 00:00', True, 1309024556, 'lDp+xHboQ2u8NmNTrDcHug==', '17MAY2015 00:00'],
    [True, '21SEP2015 00:00', '26SEP2015 00:00', True, 1309024628, 'BVNYf4MyT0S+PBjFWBUq1A==', '20SEP2015 00:00'],
    [True, '13APR2015 00:00', '18APR2015 00:00', True, 1309024536, 'pwuzfaUuQrm6n00oBoXHwA==', '12APR2015 00:00'],
    [True, '21DEC2015 00:00', '26DEC2015 00:00', True, 1309024680, 'RmbuGHxbSvKZnh9z6BIj7A==', '20DEC2015 00:00']
]
```

Comment: The result should be first available 'list' in the list 'abc', where all 1st position and 4th positions are True.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
abc = [
 [ 
    [True, "08JUN2015 00:00", "13JUN2015 00:00", False], 
    [True, "06JUL2015 00:00", "11JUL2015 00:00", True, "A", "B", "C"], 
    [True, "28SEP2015 00:00", "03OCT2015 00:00", True, "P", "Q", "R"]
 ], 
 [ 
    [True, "18MAY2015 00:00", "23MAY2015 00:00", True, "A", "B", "C"], 
    [True, "29DEC2014 00:00", "03JAN2015 00:00", False], 
    [True, "21SEP2015 00:00", "26SEP2015 00:00", True, "X", "Y", "Z"]  
 ], 
 [
    [True, "13APR2015 00:00", "18APR2015 00:00", True, "D", "E", "F"], 
    [True, "21DEC2015 00:00", "26DEC2015 00:00", True, "P", "Q", "R"], 
    [False, "06APR2015 00:00", "11APR2015 00:00", True, "Z", "U", "Y"]
 ], 
 [
    [True, "13JUL2015 00:00", "18JUL2015 00:00", True, "A","B","C"], 
    [True, "09NOV2015 00:00", "14NOV2015 00:00", False], 
    [True, "05JAN2015 00:00", "10JAN2015 00:00", True, "A", "X", "Z"], 
    [False, "19OCT2015 00:00", "24OCT2015 00:00", True, "B", "Z", "A"], 
    [True, "20JUL2015 00:00", "25JUL2015 00:00", True, "E", "F", "R"]  
 ], 
 [
    [True, "23FEB2015 00:00", "28FEB2015 00:00", True, "E", "R", "N"],  
    [True, "07DEC2015 00:00", "12DEC2015 00:00", False, "W", "T", "P"], 
    [True, "20JUL2015 00:00", "25JUL2015 00:00", True, "R", "U", "Y"]
 ],
 [
    [True, "23FEB2015 00:00", "28FEB2015 00:00", True, "A", "V", "D"],  
    [True, "07DEC2015 00:00", "12DEC2015 00:00", True, "E", "Q", "R"], 
    [True, "20JUL2015 00:00", "25JUL2015 00:00", True, "W", "R", "X"]
 ]
]
```

You can just write nested loops:

```
[sl for li in abc for sl in li if all(e is True for e in (sl[0], sl[3]))]
```

Result:

```
[[True, '06JUL2015 00:00', '11JUL2015 00:00', True, 'A', 'B', 'C'], 
 [True, '28SEP2015 00:00', '03OCT2015 00:00', True, 'P', 'Q', 'R'], 
 [True, '18MAY2015 00:00', '23MAY2015 00:00', True, 'A', 'B', 'C'], 
 [True, '21SEP2015 00:00', '26SEP2015 00:00', True, 'X', 'Y', 'Z'], 
 [True, '13APR2015 00:00', '18APR2015 00:00', True, 'D', 'E', 'F'], 
 [True, '21DEC2015 00:00', '26DEC2015 00:00', True, 'P', 'Q', 'R'], 
 [True, '13JUL2015 00:00', '18JUL2015 00:00', True, 'A', 'B', 'C'], 
 [True, '05JAN2015 00:00', '10JAN2015 00:00', True, 'A', 'X', 'Z'], 
 [True, '20JUL2015 00:00', '25JUL2015 00:00', True, 'E', 'F', 'R'], 
 [True, '23FEB2015 00:00', '28FEB2015 00:00', True, 'E', 'R', 'N'], 
 [True, '20JUL2015 00:00', '25JUL2015 00:00', True, 'R', 'U', 'Y'], 
 [True, '23FEB2015 00:00', '28FEB2015 00:00', True, 'A', 'V', 'D'], 
 [True, '07DEC2015 00:00', '12DEC2015 00:00', True, 'E', 'Q', 'R'], 
 [True, '20JUL2015 00:00', '25JUL2015 00:00', True, 'W', 'R', 'X']]
```

Comment: The result should be first available 'list' in the list 'abc', where all 1st position and 4th positions are True. the result should be a list. `[ 
       [True, 18MAY2015 00:00, 23MAY2015 00:00, True, A, B, C], 
       [True, 29DEC2014 00:00, 03JAN2015 00:00, False], 
       [True, 21SEP2015 00:00, 26SEP2015 00:00, True, X, Y, Z]  
     ]`

Comment: In your example, not all the 1st and 4th positions are `True`. Your have `[[True,,True,,,], [True,,False], [True,,True,,,]]`